# how to validate form in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a website based on codeigniter framework. I have a form on my index page and some prices of flights which are coming through my database.

here is my form:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>detail/travel" method="post">

<input type="text" name="departure">
<input type="text" name="destination">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="cell">

</form>
```

so my problem is when user did not fill the whole form and submit the button, it goes into the function of "travel" which I made in my controller(detail) and show 0 results because of the error. I want that user remain on my index page with all the details until he fill the form correctly and show errors on my index page if he missed any field of my form.

here is my function "travel" that i have in my controller(detail):

```
function search_travel(){
                if($_POST){

                    $config = array(
                    array(
                    'field'=>'departure',
                    'label'=>'departure',
                    'rules'=>'trim|required|alpha'
                    ),
                    array(
                    'field'=>'destination',
                    'label'=>'destination',
                    'rules'=>'trim|required|alpha'
                    ),
                    array(
                    'field'=>'name',
                    'label'=>'name',
                    'rules'=>'trim|required|alpha'
                    ),
                    array(
                    'field'=>'cell',
                    'label'=>'cell no',
                    'rules'=>'trim|required|regex_match[/^[0-13]+$/]'
                    )
                );
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                $data['errors']= validation_errors();
                }   
            else{       
            $destination= $this->input->post('destination');
            $this->email->send();
            $data['var']= $this->Travel->search_travel($destination);
            $this->load->view('details',$data)
              }
            }
         }
```

and my index function is:

```
function index(){
        $data['fares']= $this->Travel->all_fares();
        $this->load->view('index', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to redirect to old page and print error in view page

```
<?php echo form_error('departure'); ?>
```

(print this in view for each input fields and below in controller)

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

         redirect('method name that loads form');
      }
```

Comment: form is in the index file so In order to remain on index page with errors I  just use redirect(base_url()) ??

Comment: I am getting errors while writing <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('errors');?> in my view, This shows all the errors but i want to display under each input field. what should i Do???

Comment: as mentioned above echo form_error('filed name ) after each input field you can paste the code

Comment: I write below the input field of destination <?php echo form_error('destination');  ?> but it did not showing me the error

Comment: have you printed them with echo ?

Comment: yes like this: <?php echo form_error('destination'); ?>

Comment: should i need any change in controller: if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', validation_errors());
                 redirect(base_url());
    }

Comment: just redirect without flashdata and see if you get validation errors and redirect to controller method instead base url

Comment: yeah its working but why not working with flashdata?? is there any other way??

Comment: this is standard format for codeigniter and tick right for the ans if its working for you